# How to rotate the image so that the barcode horizontal?? - MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, rotation, hough-transform

How can I rotate the image using the barcode to determine where the angle is and rotate it according to make it horizontal. I used `Hough Transform` but I can only rotate slightly to the right.

[image: Original Image]
[image: Rotated Image]

```
rgb = imread('barcode10.jpg');
% Resize Image
rgb = imresize(rgb,0.33);
figure(),imshow(rgb);
% Convert from RGB to Gray
Igray = double(rgb2gray(rgb));
BW2 = edge(Igray,'canny');
figure(),imshow(BW2);
% Perform the Hough transform
[H, theta, rho] = hough(BW2);
 % Find the peak pt in the Hough transform
peak = houghpeaks(H);
 % Find the angle of the bars
barAngle = theta(peak(2));
J = imrotate(rgb,barAngle,'bilinear','crop');
figure(),imshow(J);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need first to detect the lines. For line detection you can use [Hough transform](http://www.mathworks.se/help/toolbox/images/ref/hough.html).

Comment: How to write that code?? I had spent few weeks reading about it and try the code but it wont works!!

Comment: You need to be more specific. What have you tried? How it doesn't work?

Comment: @Kim you wont get any helpful answers like this. You should at least try something or tell us, where EXACTLY you have your problems. Further I suppose, there are a lot of solutions for this already on the internet. So please at least use google or search the matlab file exchange :)

Comment: I tried [Detecting Lines Using the Hough Transform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f11-11942.html#f11-27827) but it only can detect some certain lines not all and afterthat I tried modify the code to detect the lines just that the result is not what I want and I also don't know how to let the program know that is the barcode.

Comment: You need to familiriaze yourself some image processing and recognization basics and ask specific questions or use some premade library to read barcodes. First step would probably be searching for barcode (black and white, high contrast), then detecting angle and decoding. That's a lot of work. Without testing myself, the images you linked are too low resolution and blurry, so it's hard to read that barcode even with proper commercial software.

Comment: I have re-ask the question, do take a look